# How can I download a flash screen as pdf using abcpdf.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, abcpdf

I have a flash calendar from which I want to download the current screen of flash as pdf, using abcpdf.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant, with abc pdf as it wont render the flash.

What you will need to do is get another program/script to screen grab the flash and then add that screen grab to a page as a image and then abc pdf can access that new page.

You need to use this method when using Googles interactive map. just replace the maps with there jpeg API.

Answer (score 1):

I've generated PDFs from flash MovieClips/objects using [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/). The PDF format can be kind of stingy sometimes but if you need the generate PDFs this is what I would use.